# How can I use DIME with WSE 3.0?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, mtom

I need to make calls to a legacy SOAP API that only supports [DIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188797.aspx), but DIME is not supported in WSE 3.0.

Unfortunately, WSE 2.0, which supports DIME, is not supported in conjunction with Visual Studio 2005.

I understand the reasons for moving to [MTOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTOM), but the need to communicate with legacy services does not disappear because a new standard is released.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am also looking for the answer to this question. Alex, if you are too, could you add some tags like C# and .Net? If not, what did you find out?

Comment: I think the answer is that DIME is no longer supported and that to make calls to a DIME Web service, WSE 2.0 is required.

Answer (score 1):

While you don't have VS 2005 support, you can still make this work. Remember that VS is a tool that makes it incredibly easy, but you can always get around it.  My proposal is that you download the WSE 2.0 and find the assembly containing DIME and other libraries you need. Then add a reference from your client to that assembly and include the namespace in your file.  The following article shows how to code the client, not saying anything about VS support:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996944.aspx

Notice the example that sets the config file to reference the right assemblies. You might have to play around with getting the right references and some manual work, but I'm sure it's possible.

The first time I used DIME was with a preview copy that MS had posted to GotDotNet, which is now gone.  I had the source code and articles like the one above, but no IDE support and got it to work just fine.

Joe